# Are there any DOM tree visualizers like Firefox's (defunct) 'Arboreal'?

Tags: html, dom, graph, graph-visualization, visualizer

I beg pardon in advance if this is the wrong place to ask about tools, but I wasn't sure which other StackExchange site would be appropriate.

I'm training some colleagues on HTML and basic CSS / jQuery selectors, and I feel it'd be very helpful for them to have an interactive DOM tree visualization - something with a broader, clearer view than the inspectors built into Firefox and Chrome.

Years ago there was a Firefox extension called [Arboreal](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/arboreal/) that looks **perfect**, but it's long-since defunct. Does anyone know of a similar tool, ideally one that's interactive and built into the browser? Any browser is fine.

Comment: I think you can easily create one by using some of the many graph drawing tools out there, where you input the DOM tree.

Comment: I could probably whip up something that graphs the DOM, but making it interactive and integrating it into the browser is beyond my available overtime lately..

Comment: Tilt is a nice visualizer, and DOM Inspector has a bit cleaner view on the DOM - both working add-ons for FireFox. However, I am too looking for an alternative and can't find anything.

Comment: @sacheie any luck on this? I am looking for something to explain to students what a DOM Tree really is and why it is called a tree...